# Environment/Setup - JavaScript Slider - "Cannot set property 'className' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, css, development-environment, environment

I decided to create small, simple slider with the help of [Sitepoint tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-simple-javascript-slideshow-without-jquery/) as a part of my practice.

Unfortunately, as the code works in their tutorial, it does return an error for me saying:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined at nextSlide

When I set everything up in the jsfiddle ( here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/9ndfhn4e/ ) everything works just fine.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Gulp Starter Environment</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
  <script src="js/j.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="slides">
      <li class="slide showing">Slide 1</li>
      <li class="slide">Slide 2</li>
      <li class="slide">Slide 3</li>
      <li class="slide">Slide 4</li>
      <li class="slide">Slide 5</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex; }

#slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none; }

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s; }

.showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2; }

.slide {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff; }

.slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red; }

.slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: orange; }

.slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: green; }

.slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: blue; }

.slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: purple; }
```

JS

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll("#slides .slide");
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

function nextSlide() {
    slides[currentSlide].className = "slide";
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = "slide showing";
}
```

I Believe it might be environment problem, but I cannot think of anything. Maybe someone has an idea.
Thanks for help .

Comment: Yes, helped, just moved the script at the bottom of the page. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

When you create a fiddle, the default settings for javscript load type is `onLoad`. This places your script in the head of the document like so:

```
<head>
...
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
            ...your code...
        }
    </script>
...
</head>
```

What I'm assuming you have done, is placed your code into the `body` of the document as you have typed it into the JSFiddle javascript editor.

The problem is, the `DOM` hasn't loaded yet and cannot find your `document.querySelectorAll("#slides .slide")` because they do not exist.

You either have to attach your code to an `onLoad` event, or place your code at the bottom of the document to ensure the `DOM` has loaded before your script executes.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for help. Now, I understand. Placed it at the bottom.